# FontAwesomeIcon React component does not accept icon property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, font-awesome, react-font-awesome

I am unable to build my React project because of Font Awesome library for react.

I have used the icons with `<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPowerOff} />` syntax until now, but after trying to implement automatic build and deploy on Github, I get the following error:

```
Type 'IconDefinition' is not assignable to type 'IconProp'.
  Type 'IconDefinition' is not assignable to type 'IconLookup'.
     Types of property 'iconName' are incompatible.
```

The icon **does** render with this syntax and the error, strangely.

With the `<FontAwesomeIcon icon={"power-off"} />` syntax, I don't get the error anymore, but the icon itself **does not** render at all.

The versions I have used since the beginning of the project:

```
├── @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core@1.3.0
├── @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons@5.15.4 
├── @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@0.1.17
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Weird behaviour.

On their [website](https://fontawesome.com/icons/1?s=solid&f=classic) they use icons in React like this:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-solid fa-1" />
```

but it didn't worked for me.

---

This also didn't worked with the newer npm package version:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={"fa-1"} />
```

---

Now I am using this, which works fine:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { fa1 } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/fa1';

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={fa1} />
```

I am using version:

```
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.1",
"@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.1",
"@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by downgrading the `fontawesome-svg-core` and `react-fontawesome` packages to the following versions:

```
├── @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core@1.2.36
├── @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@0.1.16
```